# Proof of theorem describing decay of convolution at infinity?

Tags: proof-explanation, convolution

[image]

First question: Is that inequality just cauchy schwarz inequality?

Second question: What happened on that last step, where $g(x-t) \rightarrow g(x)?$

Comment: because Lebesgue measure is translation invariant we have $\int|g(x-t)|dx=\int|g(x)|dx$ for every $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality  is  the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality). That inequality states that the absolute value of a sum is less than or equal to the sum of  absolute value. It applies to integrals (which are generalized sums).

The last step is the result of changing the variable $x \rightarrow x-t$ in the  inner integral.

Comment: ok, I was thinking the inequality was cauchy-schwarz inequality?

Comment: No, that inequality is different. Check it out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Answer (score 1):

The inequality in the proof is just the inequality $|\int h(t)| dt \leq \int |h(t)|dt$ (which has no name). The fact that $\int |g(x-t)| dx=\int |g(x)|dx$ is obtained by making the substitution $z=x-t$. [$\int |g(x)|dx$ is same as $\int |g(z)|dz$]. In measure thoretic language this property is called translation invariance of Lebesgue measure].